# How do you run the Openerp 7 built in unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, odoo, openerp-7, python-unittest

How do you run the unit tests for the built in modules? I've tried starting the server with:

```
./openerp-server -c /path/to/config -d my_database -u stock --log-level=test
```

but nothing shows up in the logs. In my config, I've also tried setting

```
test_enable = True
```

How do I get the test results to show up in the logs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tests are launched when you install or update modules. If you want to launch the tests of the sale module and all it's dependencies, you have to create a demo database and

```
./openerp-server --addons-path=... -d mydb --log-level=test -i sale --test-enable
```

The argument --log-level=test is not required, but if you omit it, you will not see the logs of all tests that are executed.

Optionally, you can add:

```
--test-report-directory=/tmp
```

If you develop on the sale module, you can run the server with the same argumentsn but with -u instead of -i (and avoid the createdb command) so that it relaunches only the tests of the sale module.